# What is explanation for the names given to the supervisor restart strategies?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, erlang-supervisor

OTP supervisor restart strategy names seems weird to me, maybe because I'm not a native English speaker.

- `one_for_one`: when one child dies, it restarts that child
- `one_for_all`: when one child dies, it kills all other children and restarts them in order
- `rest_for_one`: when one child dies, it kills all children booted after that dead children, and restarts them in order

I am trying to understand these strategy names by reading them as sentences, e.g. "restart `one` child `for` `one` child's death".
Then either `one_for_all` or `rest_for_one` seems an inverted name to me. (`"restart one child for all children's death"`??)

Why were these strategies named like this?

c.f. [The erlang docs `one_for_all` section](http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/sup_princ.html#id79244) has a figure saying "all-for-one supervision". Is this just a typo?

Comment: ...and to be consistent why isn't `rest_for_one` named `one_for_rest`?  I propose the names be changed to:  `failed`, `failed_and_after`, `all`.

Comment: This puzzles me everyday. I am glad to see I am not the only one. To me it is `one_for_all` that is misnamed.

Answer (score 2):

[There are:](https://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/sup_princ.html#supervisor-flags)

```
    strategy() = one_for_all
               | one_for_one
               | rest_for_one
               | simple_one_for_one
```

> I will skip `simple_one_for_one` and focus on the other three.

I believe the names for the restarts strategies are derived from the [English idiom](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/one_for_all,_all_for_one#English) "One for all, all for one". The expression appears to be quite [old](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unus_pro_omnibus,_omnes_pro_uno).

`one_for_one`: meaning one goes and is replaced by a newly started child process.

`one_for_all`: meaning (from the idiom) that if *one* terminates then we (children) *all* terminate and start again.

`rest_for_one`: if one goes down then the *rest* also terminates, and starts up again. The "rest" in this case is referring to all the *succeeding* (behind) children in the [start order](https://erlang.org/doc/man/supervisor.html#supervision-principles) specified. Note that the only difference between this and the one above is respecting the start order.

I prefer to think of them as a "single" strategy (ie `one_for_one`) and a "full" strategy (ie `one_for_all` and `rest_for_one`). In most cases this will work just fine.

Comment: I understand that `one_for_all` comes from the old "One for all" idiom. My question is, then why isn't the other one named `one_for_rest`? It's so confusing.

Comment: Yes, I understand that would follow the same pattern as the others. Frankly, I do not know. The only reason I can think of is that it is the only one taking start order in to account.

Comment: `one_for_all` takes start order into account as it will shutdown remaining children in reverse order and then start all children in defined order.

Comment: rest_for_one implies that the rest are terminated for the 'one' (which has gone down), whereas one_for_rest would imply that one is terminated for the 'rest' (that have gone down). Whilst the latter may be strictly true, I think that ordering has different connotations, and the former definitely makes more sense to me. There will doubtless be explicit grammatical rules defining exactly why that is, but as a native English speaker, rest_for_one makes way more sense to me than one_for_rest.

Answer (score -2):

"'Cause when it's all for one it's one for all." Bryan Adams or the three musketeers

so you restart all for when one goes down, or you restart rest for when one goes down.